# fork() Process Issue on Channel Switching via Rotary Encoder

Tags: gpio, python, pi-zero-w, communication

I have KY040 rotary switcher(encoder) as shown below picture.

[image]

It is the scenario that there are 5 radio stations(simple html url) in `urls.txt` which are read into `stations` list in `radyoCS.py`, at every switch(turn) station is changed. I'm using the rotary switch to do that. The radio player is [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) which can be run via terminal like `mplayer -playlist <url>`. `playStation(numberOfStation)`  uses `subprocess.Popen(....)` to run MPlayer with the given station. It simply switches between the urls. **The problem is after 2nd switch the application is stuck.** The way is my solution. If you have any better idea, please let me know.

radyoCs.py

```
import os

import re
import subprocess


### READ RADIO STATIONS FROM FILE AT FIRST ###

playlist = ["m3u", "pls", "asx"]

f = open('urls.txt', 'r')
stations = [line for line in f.readlines()]
f.close()

print('\n'.join(str(p) for p in stations))

### FUNCTIONS ###
def playStation(i):
    os.system("killall mplayer")
    if any(x in stations[i] for x in playlist):
        radioName = 'mplayer ' + '-prefer-ipv4 ' + '-playlist ' + stations[i]
        p = subprocess.Popen(radioName.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    else:
        radioName = 'mplayer ' + '-prefer-ipv4 ' + stations[i]
        p = subprocess.Popen(radioName.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)


    ### the below part is to grap radio station name and track being played and print ###
    for line in p.stdout:
        if line.startswith(('ICY Info:'.encode(), 'Name'.encode())):
            if 'Name'.encode() in line:
                nameStr = str(line)
                searchRadioName = re.search(r'(?<=:\s).*?(?=\\n)', nameStr, re.M | re.I)
                if searchRadioName:
                    print(searchRadioName.group())

            if 'ICY Info:'.encode() in line:
                trackStr = str(line)
                searchTrackName = re.search(r'(?<=\=\').*?(?=\'\;)', trackStr, re.M | re.I)
                if searchTrackName:
                    print(searchTrackName.group())
    return p
```

main.py

```
import os
import signal
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

import radyoCS


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

### PINS ###
CLOCKPIN = 16
DATAPIN = 15
SWITCHPIN = 14

# setup pins
GPIO.setup(CLOCKPIN, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(DATAPIN, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(SWITCHPIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


MIN_LIMIT_CHANNEL = 0
MAX_LIMIT_CHANNEL = 5

# for testing purpose, it is actually 0
counter = 2


try:
    while True:

        pid = os.fork()

        if pid == 0:
            print("i'm child my pid => " + str(os.getpid()) + "my parent => " + str(os.getppid()))
            #radyoCS.playStation(t)
            print(counter)

            ### normally playStation does work, control is takeovered by '''mplayer''' !!!!
            time.sleep(100)
        else:
            ### wait until rotary switcher turns
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(CLOCKPIN, GPIO.FALLING)

            clock = GPIO.input(CLOCKPIN)
            data = GPIO.input(DATAPIN)

            ### stop current child to create new child
            ### stop currently playing radio station to change to new station
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)

            print("i'm waiting, value t > " + str(t))

            ### We have 5 radio stations, if data==1 turned counter clokwise, otherwise clockwise
            if data == 1:
                if counter == MIN_LIMIT_CHANNEL:
                    counter = MAX_LIMIT_CHANNEL + 1
                counter -= 1
            else:
                if counter == MAX_LIMIT_CHANNEL:
                    counter = MIN_LIMIT_CHANNEL - 1
                counter += 1


        sleep(0.1)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

urls.txt

```
http://rss-streaming.co.uk:8062/listen.pls?sid=1
http://142.4.206.137:26284/
http://dir.xiph.org/listen/922068/listen.m3u
http://retroserver.streamr.ru:8043/retro128.m3u
http://stream.funradio.sk:8000/80-90-128.mp3.m3u
http://www.guldkanalen.se/static/streamGK/WMA.asx
```

Minimal `fork()` part,

```
try:
    while True:

        pid = os.fork()

        if pid == 0:
            print("i'm child my pid => " + str(os.getpid()) + "my parent => " + str(os.getppid()))
            #radyoCS.playStation(t)
            print(counter)

            ### normally playStation does work, control is takeovered by '''mplayer''' !!!!
            time.sleep(100)
        else:
            ### wait until rotary switcher turns
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(CLOCKPIN, GPIO.FALLING)

            clock = GPIO.input(CLOCKPIN)
            data = GPIO.input(DATAPIN)

            ### stop current child to create new child
            ### stop currently playing radio station to change to new station
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)

            print("i'm waiting, value t > " + str(counter))

            ### We have 5 radio stations, if data==1 turned counter clokwise, otherwise clockwise
        if data == 1:   # counter clokwise
            if counter == MIN_LIMIT_CHANNEL:
                counter = MAX_LIMIT_CHANNEL + 1
            counter -= 1
        else:           # clockwise
            if counter == MAX_LIMIT_CHANNEL:
                counter = MIN_LIMIT_CHANNEL - 1
            counter += 1


        sleep(0.1)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have killed the process, but a dead process doesn't disappear from
>   the process table until its parent process performs a task called
>   "reaping" (essentially calling `wait(3)` for that process to read its
>   exit status).   Dead processes that haven't been reaped are called
>   "[zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)."

When I call several times after some rotations `ps --ppid <parent pid>`, I see that,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps --ppid 801
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  815 pts/1    00:00:00 python3.5 <defunct>
  819 pts/1    00:00:00 python3.5 <defunct>
  830 pts/1    00:00:00 python3.5 <defunct>
  831 pts/1    00:00:00 python3.5 <defunct>
  850 pts/1    00:00:00 python3.5 <defunct>
```

**Rule of thumb:** Even though the child is killed via another signal or self-annihilation(`os.exit(..)`), eventually burial procedures must be done by **its parent**, that is, let the child go to the happy hunting grounds by calling `os.wait(...)`